# Appending a data frame with for if and else statements or how do put print in dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, append

How do I put what I printed in a dataframe with a for loop and if else statements?
Basically, this code:

```
list<-c("10","20","5")
for (j in 1:3){
  if (list[j] < 8) 
    print("Greater")
  else print("Less")
})
#[1] "Less"
#[1] "Less"
#[1] "Greater"
```

Or should it be something more like this?

```
f3 <- function(n){
  df <- data.frame(x = numeric(n), y = character(n), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  for(j in 1:3){
    if (list[j] < 8)
    df$x[j] <- j
    df$y[j] <- toString(Greater)
    else
    df$y[j] <- toString(Less)
  }
  df
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to try to add rows one-at-a-time to a data.frame. it's better to generate all the column data at once and then throw it into a data.frame. For your specific example, the `ifelse()` function can help

```
list<-c(10,20,5)
data.frame(x=list, y=ifelse(list<8, "Greater","Less"))
```

Comment: This prints 
`x       y
1 10 Greater
2 20 Greater
3  5 Greater`

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger I forgot I had changed the character to numeric values. I put my list in the post. This could also be done with `as.numeric(list)`. The OP's original code would have printed "Greater" three times as well.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realise the OP had characters and I just copy'pasted his list assignment.